# Node.js insert variables into loaded Gumroad API

Tags: node.js, api

I'm new to node.js, I was creating a script to verify **Serial** and **Product** with the **Gumroad** Api package.
From a script I load two variables from an html file and send them to the node server
The node receives them and they are displayed, but I cannot get them to be read by the gumroad package function.

This is the script in send variables page ( and works )

```
$.post('http://localhost:3000/node_server_test/', {
serial:'xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx',
product:'product_id'
});
```

The node.js retrive the variables well.
I report only the part of the code concerned.

```
  app.post('/node_server_test', (req, res) => {
  var a = req.body.product;
  var b = req.body.serial;
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);

// var a = "product_id";
// var b = "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx"


gumroad.verifyLicense(a,b)
.then(function(license) {
  console.log('Licence Valid');

}, function() {
  console.log('Invalid Licence');

});

});
```

in this mode the data is read and reported correctly in the console, but they are not read by the `gumroad.verifyLicense(a,b)` function, the **serial** / **product** pair is **always** **invalid**.

If instead I remove the comments from the variable declarations for the function

```
var a = "product_id";
var b = "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx"
```

the function returns the correct result.

It's possible to do it? where am i wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what is the console output from the code you show above? (the values of a, b and either "License Valid" or "Invalid License"). Maybe also do a `console.log(req.body)` to see its structure.

Comment: Thanks, now works, the problem was a Gumroad API.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's declared as not a problem by the OP